# Sort DOM elements by comma-separated values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Given a random sorted list, each with a `data-combi` attribute (a comma separated list of numbers), I'd like to sort them in the right order

```
<ul class="result">  
  <li data-combi="10,16,24">Combination: 10,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="8,7,23">Combination: 8,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,16,23">Combination: 9,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="8,7,24">Combination: 8,7,24</li>  
  <li data-combi="8,16,24">Combination: 8,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,23">Combination: 9,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,16,23">Combination: 10,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,24">Combination: 9,7,24</li>  
  <li data-combi="9,16,24">Combination: 9,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="8,16,23">Combination: 8,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,23">Combination: 10,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,24">Combination: 10,7,24</li>
</ul>
```

I'm using this code to sort elements but, since `data-combi` is a string, the sort result is technically right (ie. "10" is sorted before "9", or "16" is sorted before "7") but not the wanted one:

```
var $combiUl = $('ul.result');
var $combiLi = $combiUl.children();

$combiLi.sort(function(a,b){
  var an = a.getAttribute('data-combi');
  var bn = b.getAttribute('data-combi');
  return (an > bn) ? 1 : ((an < bn) ? -1 : 0);
});
// deatch variants and re-append in correct order
$combiLi.detach().appendTo($combiUl);
```

In my ideal world, each comma separated value in the `data-combi` attribute should be treated as number, not as a string, thus resulting in the following correct sort:

```
<ul class="expected">
  <li data-combi="8,7,23">Combination: 8,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="8,7,24">Combination: 8,7,24</li>
  <li data-combi="8,16,23">Combination: 8,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="8,16,24">Combination: 8,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,23">Combination: 9,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,24">Combination: 9,7,24</li>
  <li data-combi="9,16,23">Combination: 9,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,16,24">Combination: 9,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,23">Combination: 10,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,24">Combination: 10,7,24</li>
  <li data-combi="10,16,23">Combination: 10,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,16,24">Combination: 10,16,24</li>
</ul>
```

How to achieve this goal? Please consider that I can have longer or shorter comma-separated strings (ie. `10,7,23,12`, or `10,7`) depending which options the user choose to "mix". Anyway, the length of comma-separated string for each row is consistent and does not change (they contains always N comma-separated items; I cannot have one row like `10,7,23`, another like `9,5` and another like `8,2,24,6`)

Please, any idea? Here is the snippet showing what's going on

```js
var $combiUl = $('ul.result');
var $combiLi = $combiUl.children();

$combiLi.sort(function(a,b){
  var an = a.getAttribute('data-combi');
  var bn = b.getAttribute('data-combi');
  return (an > bn) ? 1 : ((an < bn) ? -1 : 0);
});
// deatch variants and re-append in correct order
$combiLi.detach().appendTo($combiUl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>the following "li" are sorted by "data-combi" attribute: since this is a string, the sort is technically right, but this is not what I am trying to achieve</p>
<ul class="result">  
  <li data-combi="10,16,24">Combination: 10,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="8,7,23">Combination: 8,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,16,23">Combination: 9,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="8,7,24">Combination: 8,7,24</li>  
  <li data-combi="8,16,24">Combination: 8,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,23">Combination: 9,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,16,23">Combination: 10,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,24">Combination: 9,7,24</li>  
  <li data-combi="9,16,24">Combination: 9,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="8,16,23">Combination: 8,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,23">Combination: 10,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,24">Combination: 10,7,24</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Turn the string into an array of numbers: `const a_arr = an.split(',').map(n => +n);` Loop through it and sort according to the values.

Comment: If this list is created by some other data collection, it'll be easier to sort that array before creating the list than to sort the DOM nodes after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to split on the commas and convert to numbers. The if/else could be cleaned up, but this is the basic idea.

```js
var $combiUl = $('ul.result');
var $combiLi = $combiUl.children(); 

$combiLi.sort(function(a,b){
  var an = a.getAttribute('data-combi').split(',').map(Number);
  var bn = b.getAttribute('data-combi').split(',').map(Number);
  var c1 = an[0] - bn[0]
  var c2 = an[1] - bn[1]
  var c3 = an[2] - bn[2]
  if (c1>0) return 1
  else if (c1<0) return -1
  else if (c2>0) return 1
  else if (c2<0) return -1
  else if (c3>0) return 1
  else if (c3<0) return -1
  else return 0
});
// deatch variants and re-append in correct order
$combiLi.detach().appendTo($combiUl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>the following "li" are sorted by "data-combi" attribute: since this is a string, the sort is technically right, but this is not what I am trying to achieve</p>
<ul class="result">  
  <li data-combi="10,16,24">Combination: 10,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="8,7,23">Combination: 8,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,16,23">Combination: 9,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="8,7,24">Combination: 8,7,24</li>  
  <li data-combi="8,16,24">Combination: 8,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,23">Combination: 9,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,16,23">Combination: 10,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,24">Combination: 9,7,24</li>  
  <li data-combi="9,16,24">Combination: 9,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="8,16,23">Combination: 8,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,23">Combination: 10,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,24">Combination: 10,7,24</li>
</ul>
```

The if/else could be replaced with a loop

```js
var $combiUl = $('ul.result');
var $combiLi = $combiUl.children(); 

$combiLi.sort(function(a,b){
  var an = a.getAttribute('data-combi').split(',').map(Number);
  var bn = b.getAttribute('data-combi').split(',').map(Number);
  for (let x in an) {
    if (an[x] > bn[x]) return 1
    if (an[x] < bn[x]) return -1
  }
  return 0
});
// deatch variants and re-append in correct order
$combiLi.detach().appendTo($combiUl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>the following "li" are sorted by "data-combi" attribute: since this is a string, the sort is technically right, but this is not what I am trying to achieve</p>
<ul class="result">  
  <li data-combi="10,16,24">Combination: 10,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="8,7,23">Combination: 8,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,16,23">Combination: 9,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="8,7,24">Combination: 8,7,24</li>  
  <li data-combi="8,16,24">Combination: 8,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,23">Combination: 9,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,16,23">Combination: 10,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="9,7,24">Combination: 9,7,24</li>  
  <li data-combi="9,16,24">Combination: 9,16,24</li>
  <li data-combi="8,16,23">Combination: 8,16,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,23">Combination: 10,7,23</li>
  <li data-combi="10,7,24">Combination: 10,7,24</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great and concise! I was stuck in the loop, I tried the jQuery `$.each(an, function(x){ ... })` with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines:

```
$combiLi.sort(function(a,b){
  var an = a.getAttribute('data-combi');
  var bn = b.getAttribute('data-combi');
  return (an > bn) ? 1 : ((an < bn) ? -1 : 0);
});
```

to this:

```
$combiLi.sort(function (a, b) {
    let an = a.getAttribute('data-combi').split(",").join("");
    let bn = b.getAttribute('data-combi').split(",").join("");
    return an - bn;
});
```

You will be able to do it without loops.

Comment: `['11,1,13','1,11,15'].sort(function (a, b) {
    let an = a.split(",").join("");
    let bn = b.split(",").join("");
    console.log(an, bn)
    return an - bn;
});`